# Group by row but give highest value of other row

Tags: sql

Query:

```sql
SELECT
    ID, Name, Component, Version 
FROM
    modules 
WHERE 
    modules.ValidTo > NOW() AND modules.ValidFrom < Now();
```

returns:

| ID | Name | Component | Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | TC1 | a | 1.0.0 |
| 13 | TC2 | b | 1.0.0 |
| 15 | TC3 | c | 1.2.0 |
| 17 | TC3 | c | 1.2.5 |

Desired data (group by Component but return record with highest Version):

| ID | Name | Component | Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | TC1 | a | 1.0.0 |
| 13 | TC2 | b | 1.0.0 |
| 17 | TC3 | c | 1.2.5 |

I have tried this query

```
SELECT
    modules.ID, modules.Name, modules.ComponentIdentifier,
    EXEName, MAX(Version)
FROM
    modules
WHERE 
    modules.ValidTo > NOW() AND modules.ValidFrom < Now()
GROUP BY
    modules.ComponentIdentifier;
```

But it returns the wrong ID. I would need the ID 17 not 15.

| ID | Name | Component | Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | TC1 | a | 1.0.0 |
| 13 | TC2 | b | 1.0.0 |
| 15 | TC3 | c | 1.2.5 |

How to solve this?

Comment: which db you are using???

Comment: Your "i tried" query contains more columns than your desired output. Where does EXEName fit into the picture?

Comment: Given that your query runs at all with that broken groupby and the NOW(), I'm gonna guess it's MySQL not in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode.. If so, hopefully it's version 8+ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using group by in improper way .. normally the select for not aggregated  column not mention in group by is not allowed .
in some db this allowed (mysql versione <5.7 or with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disabled) but produce impredictable result
then if you can't  add aggregation function to the column not mendtiond in group by
you need  subquery for filter the correct value

```
select modules.ID, modules.Name, modules.ComponentIdentifier,
    EXEName, a.max_ver 
from  (
    SELECT
    modules.ComponentIdentifier,
     MAX(Version) max_ver
    FROM   modules
    WHERE  modules.ValidTo > NOW() AND modules.ValidFrom < Now()
    GROUP BY  modules.ComponentIdentifie
    ) a 
INNER JOIN  modules on modules.ComponentIdentifier = a.ComponentIdentifier 
   and a.max_ver= modules.Version
```

Comment: Thanks but im getting: #1054 - Unknown column 'a.max_ver' in 'field list'

Comment: answer  updated ..  typo error max_bet instead of max_ver

Comment: Now i get #1054 - Unknown column 'a.Version' in 'on clause', changed a.Version to a.max_ver. Now its working. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: .. answer  updated .. a.max_ver